# Capturing F5, Back, Forward, clicking on link actions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show a popup when a user close the browser and that popup will redirect to some google survey that we need to do.

Currently by using `onbeforeunload` function in JavaScript it's prompting me the popup but I only need popup when the user closes the browser or they enter a new url.

Is there any way to prevent this function to not fire when page is refreshed, or user goes back or forward and if it can be done then how will I redirect to a survey page. Or if we can't prevent then there is any logic to do this.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. These events are outside your control for security reasons.

You're probably best off finding a different solution for your problem.

Comment: Thank goodness it's not possible, could you imagine all the spam ads that cause you to go back to their site everytime you tried to close them???!

Comment: But @Skuld, you are the 1,000,000th visitor to my site and have won an iPad! Just stay a little longer.